# How calculate div background image size on resize window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, responsive

i have some problem which i can't figure out. 
so 
i have a div with background image.

```
<div class="a"></div>
```

and i want to make clickable some point of this background image. It's okey i can make this with adding to some div width z-index and make it clickable and positioning this with position:absolute e.g,

```
<div class="b">
<a class="clickablePoint" href="#"></a>
</div>
```

but how i can keep this clickable point on the same way when i resize the window if my background-image must be a responsive so background-size:100% auto.

maybe have some method to calculate background image height realtime when resize window ? or any other method? :(

Comment: Can you use `<canvas>` with javascript?

Comment: have example how ?

Comment: Okey but how understand e.g if clickablePoint left:20% and top:60% on background-image on some resoulition what will be on another ?

Comment: The same percentages. Isn't that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a minimal viable solution showing how to absolutely-position an element based on a full-width (`background-size: 100% auto`) background.

I'm setting the `font-size` of the element to `1vw` (1/100th of the width of the viewport) and then calculating its left/top position and width/height size in `em` units, which become equivalent to a multiple of that `1vw`.

As such, resizing this demo to any size will keep the box in the same place around the cat's nose.

```css
body {
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/sVz3YRx.jpg');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 50vw; /* for stack snippet height */
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.nose {
  border: 1px solid yellow; /* for demo */
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1vw;
  top: 27em;
  left: 59em;
  width: 6em;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<a class="nose"></a>
```